# GeoTools: Calculate length along line from start vertex up to some point on the line?

Tags: java, geotools, snapping, jts-topology-suite

I have single LineString and some Point (outside the line), I snapped it to the Line (using `DistanceOp` so as far as I understood the snapped point should lay on the line). How can I calculate length along the line from start vertex of the LineString up to the snapped point on the line?

```
    import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
    import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
    import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
    import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
    import com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.distance.DistanceOp;

    GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
    Point outsidePoint = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(outside.lat, outside.lon));
    Coordinate snappedPoint = DistanceOp.nearestPoints(outsidePoint, LineString)[1];
```

I though about this: `LineString` is a `List` of coordinates, Find the index of the vertex, closest to the snapped point, and replace it with the snapped point. Then construct a `LineString` from start vertex up to the index found. Then sum length calculated between each consecutive vertices of the line.

1. First problem is situation like this:
   [image]
2. Second problem: When some sophisticated algorithm calculates length - Does inside happening something more complex than just sum lengths between 2 consecutive points?

Comment: Doesn't my answer solve your problem? Could you explain what's missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Try this:

```
public static double calculateLengthAlongLineString(LineString theLine, Coordinate coordinateOnTheLine){
    GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();
    double length = 0;
    // create point to check for intersection with line
    Point pointOnTheLine = factory.createPoint(coordinateOnTheLine);
    Coordinate[] theLineCoordinates = theLine.getCoordinates();
    // iterate over linestring and create sub-lines for each coordinate pair
    for(int i = 1; i < theLineCoordinates.length; i++){
        LineString currentLine = factory.createLineString(new Coordinate[]{theLineCoordinates[i-1], theLineCoordinates[i]});
        // check if coordinateOnTheLine is on currentLine
        if(currentLine.intersects(pointOnTheLine)){
            // create new currentLine with coordinateOnTheLine as endpoint and calculate length
            currentLine = factory.createLineString(new Coordinate[]{theLineCoordinates[i-1], coordinateOnTheLine});
            length += currentLine.getLength();
            // return result length
            return length;
        }
        length += currentLine.getLength();
    }
    // coordinate was not on the line -> return length of complete linestring...
    return length;
}
```

This approach is similar to what you already suggested. Each LineString segment is checked for intersection with the point (coordinate) and then the length is summed up.

**2)**

Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

JTS has an official solution for this:

```java
import org.locationtech.jts.linearref.LengthLocationMap;
import org.locationtech.jts.linearref.LinearLocation;
import org.locationtech.jts.linearref.LocationIndexedLine;

public static double getLengthAloneLineString(LineString line, Point point) {
    return getLengthAloneLineString(line, point.getCoordinate());
}

public static double getLengthAloneLineString(LineString line, Coordinate coordinate) {
    LocationIndexedLine locationIndexedLine = new LocationIndexedLine(line);
    LinearLocation location = locationIndexedLine.project(coordinate);
    double length = new LengthLocationMap(line).getLength(location);

    return length;
}
```

For details see source code of [JTS LocationIndexedLine](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/linearref/LengthIndexedLine.java#L117) and [JTS LengthLocationMap](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/linearref/LengthLocationMap.java#L183)